# Longitudinal beta regression with random effects

Tags: proportion

I'm interested in modeling a proportion outcome (malaria positivity rate) as a function of some discrete and categorical variables.

The dependent variable was measured repeatedly over time (3 years).

I have not yet found any literature to help with the computational support to do so, also in how to interpret the coefficients.

I'd like to implement a beta regression to model my data.

Comment: You can do this in R with `glmmTMB` or `brms` (possibly among others).  Can you say more about what the random effects would be, e.g. have you measured malaria in multiple geographic regions?  Is there a reason you can't use the denominators in modeling (i.e., number of tests done), so using a binomial or beta-binomial model? Beta is usually restricted to the case of proportion data with *unknown* denominators ...

Comment: Why not use random effects logistic regression, or possibly a GEE model for longitudinal analysis?

Comment: Thanks for the help
I hope the following details can help enrich the contributions  
The positivity rate is obtained by dividing the number of malaria cases confirmed by test by the total number of subjects tested in each health facility

this rate was measured three times in each health facility;
the rate was measured in 4 different locations (districts) 
the covariates are:  Population covered by the health facility
   district in which the H.F. is located
   the period in which the rate was measured

Comment: I will look in to the other options you mentioned!!